# Analysis Of Planar Frame Using Hardy Cross Method (Moment Distribution) With Sway

Tags: structural-analysis, statics, strength

The image shown below is a sketch of the structure/frame that I am attempting to analyse using the Hardy Cross (Moment Distribution) Method. I need to find the bending moments, axial forces and shear forces on each of the individual members. After that, I am planning to apply the design equations according to codes.

The main reason I am stuck is due to the sway generated by the unsymmetric nature of the structure. I am unsure about where to apply the arbitrary sway load and also how the joint rotations are related (using displacement triangles). I need these details in order to analyse the structure using Moment Distribution with Sway. Software is not an option as I do not have access to it.

[image: Geometry and Loading of Frame]

Please demonstrate how to solve the structure (mainly find the bending moments).